# Import IIFE function from another file

Tags: javascript, function, web, iife

I got a JS file from the server that contains an IIFE function and returns a function, my question is, How I can import it to my main JavaScript file and calling the returned function.

My IIFE file look like this:

```
var MyIIFE = function() {
    return function(i) {
      return i;
    }
}();
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you include that js file in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Once you import and execute the above IIFE, your variable `MyIIFE` will be a reference to function. So if you invoke it `var result = MyIIFE(3);` your variable `result` will contain the number `3`.